# Frozen on [phonegap] executing 'cordova run'

Tags: android, cordova, terminal, android-studio

I am trying to run my application via USB on my two tablets.
The command is

```
phonegap run
```

On 1 of them it runs perfectly.
On the other it freezes on

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run'...
```

I have left it for about 10 minutes and it has not changed.

They both have developer options and USB debugging enabled.

Is there anything else that stops the command from running?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running `phonegap build android` and then install `.apk` file on your device manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but using the `phonegap build` command, but I believe the solution is similar.

To solve use the option `--verbose` (probably `phonegap run --verbose`) to see all messages generated in the build process. From there you will have an idea how to solve.

In my case I had to edit the file `/myapp/config.xml` and change `android-minSdkVersion` to 10 and everything worked normally.

Comment: --verbose helped me, in my case it was downloading large files, thank you